# Stripping the newtype constructor

Tags: haskell, constructor, strip, syntactic-sugar, newtype

More often than not I am writing functions that are stripping the only constructor of a new type, such as in the following function to return the first argument that is not Nothing:

```
process (Pick xs) = (\(First x) -> x) . mconcat . map (First . process) $ xs
```

I think the lambda is unnecessarily verbose. I would like to write something like this:

```
process (Pick xs) = -First . mconcat . map (First . process) $ xs
```

Do the meta programming facilities of Haskell allow for anything similar to this? Any other solution to solve this problem in a more concise way is also welcome.

UPD. The whole code has been requested:

```
data Node where
  Join :: [Node] -> Node
  Pick :: [Node] -> Node
  Given :: Maybe String -> Node
  Name :: String -> Node

process :: Node -> Maybe String
process (Join xs) = liftM os_path_join (mapM process xs)
process (Pick xs) = getFirst . mconcat . map (First . process) $ xs
process (Name x) = Just x
process (Given x) = x
```

Comment: Sounds like `coerce`.

Comment: What is the type of `process` supposed to be?  It might be possible to use the `newtype` package to hide most of this.  All I can make of it is that `Pick` must belong to a recursive type, since `Pick :: [a] -> PickType`, and `process :: PickType -> Maybe a`, but `First . process :: PickType -> First a`, so `xs :: [PickType]`?

Comment: It's just a toy example, but I'll add it to the OP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Zeta suggested in the comments, [`coerce`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-Coerce.html#v:coerce) is a nice, general way to do this:

```
process (Pick xs) = coerce . mconcat . map (First . process) $ xs
```

Another nice thing about `coerce` is that you can use it to coerce "inside" of a type constructor at no runtime cost, like this:

```
example :: [Sum Int] -> [Int]
example = coerce
```

The alternative, `map getFirst`, would induce a runtime overhead for the `map` traversal.

Also, every time you make a `newtype`, GHC automatically makes the appropriate `Coercible` instance so you never have to worry about messing with the underlying machinery (you don't even need `deriving` for it):

```
newtype Test = Test Char

example2 :: Maybe Test -> Maybe Char
example2 = coerce
```

Comment: I encounter a problem with `coerce`. When trying `toList $ coerce x` where x is instance of newtype wrapper for `Foldable` type Haskell fails to deduce correct types

Answer (score 5):

In this case you can actually use the `newtypes` package to solve this problem more generically:

```
process :: Node -> Maybe String
process (Pick xs) = ala' First foldMap process xs
process (Join xs) = liftM os_path_join (mapM process xs)
process (Name x) = Just x
process (Given x) = x
```

You could even have a more generic version that takes a `Newtype n (Maybe String)` like

```
process'
    :: (Newtype n (Maybe String), Monoid n)
    => (Maybe String -> n) -> Node -> Maybe String
process' wrapper (Pick xs) = ala' wrapper foldMap (process' wrapper) xs
process' wrapper (Join xs) = liftM os_path_join (mapM (process' wrapper) xs)
process' wrapper (Name x) = Just x
process' wrapper (Given x) = x
```

Then

```
> let processFirst = process' First
> let processLast = process' Last
> let input = Pick [Given Nothing, Name "bar", Given (Just "foo"), Given Nothing]
> processFirst input
Just "bar"
> ProcessLast input
Just "foo"
```

As an explanation for how this works, the `ala'` function takes a newtype wrapper to determine the instance of `Newtype` to use, a function which in this case we want to be `foldMap`:

```
foldMap :: (Monoid m, Foldable t) => (a -> m) -> t a -> m
```

since `foldMap f` ends up being a generalized `mconcat . map f` over `Foldable` types instead of just lists, then a function to use as a "preprocessor" for hooking into the higher-order function being passed to `ala'` (`foldMap`), then in this case some `Foldable t => t Node` to process.  If you didn't want the preprocessing step you'd just use `ala`, which uses `id` for its preprocessor.  Using this function can sometimes be difficult due to its complex type, but as the examples in the documentation show `foldMap` is often a good choice.

The power of this is if you wanted to write your own `newtype` wrapper for `Maybe String`:

```
newtype FirstAsCaps = FirstAsCaps { getFirstAsCaps :: Maybe String }

firstAsCaps :: Maybe String -> FirstAsCaps
firstAsCaps = FirstAsCaps . fmap (fmap toUpper)

instance Monoid FirstAsCaps where
    mempty = firstAsCaps Nothing
    mappend (FirstAsCaps f) (FirstAsCaps g)
        = FirstAsCaps $ ala First (uncurry . on (<>)) (f, g)

instance Newtype FirstAsCaps (Maybe String) where
    pack = firstAsCaps
    unpack = getFirstAsCaps
```

Then

```
> process' firstAsCaps input
Just "BAR"
```

Comment: The package is called newtype: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/newtype

Answer (score 4):

If you're using `Data.Monoid.First`, then this is just `getFirst`.  Many newtype wrappers use record syntax to provide an easy function to unwrap the newtype.

Answer (score 4):

Meta programming looks overly complex for this. I'd simply use

```
unFirst (First x) = x  -- define once, use many times

process (Pick xs) = unFirst . mconcat . map (First . process) $ xs
```

It is often the case that a function is defined together with the newtype, e.g.

```
newtype First a = First { unFirst :: a }
```

Comment: Thanks. This is better, but if I need to write lots of newtypes, it would still be nice to have something, like what I requested. Even though at this point it seems that records are the best I could do, I have a personal prejudice against them (in this form they also seem redundant and repetitive; even you made a mistake of prefixing the Constructor name with and "un", as opposed to "get", and in my opinion there should exist a uniform treatment of this case).

Comment: @NioBium The only current uniform way is, as you write, `(\(First x)->x)` which is cumbersome but not that long. I however agree that having a more direct uniform way could be nice. In the libraries you also find `run-` as a common prefix for the inverse operation, at least in the context of monadic newtypes.